# Improper integral and moment-generating function of a function of exponential distributions

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, moment-generating-functions

So I was trying to find the moment-generating function to the following random variable: $X^{2}+Y^{2}$ such that $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim Exp(2\lambda)$, independent to each other. I thought of only finding the distribution of each and using the property:

$M_{X_{1}+X_{2}=M_{X_{1}}.M_{X_{2}}}$
\begin{align}
X^{2}&=Z\\
\sqrt{z}&=X\\
f_{Z}&=f_{X}(\sqrt{z})\left| \frac{dx}{dz}  \right|\\
&=\lambda e^{-\lambda\sqrt{z}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}
\end{align}
So the moment-generating function would be:

\begin{align}
E(e^{zt}) &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda\sqrt{z}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}e^{tz}dz\\
&=\frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}e^{-\lambda\sqrt{z}+zt}dz
\end{align}

Comment: are you sure with $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$$?

Comment: What is $z$, a parameter like $\lambda$ and $t$?

Comment: Please provide the context from which this integral came.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the post. I was a little lazy as a question I asked a few days ago and I did really nice formating was tottaly ignored.